# How can I increase my English vocabulary?

Tags: meaning, american-english

How can I increase my English vocabulary? Because I feel my knowledge of words is very limited when I talk with another people.

Comment: A better site for your question is _Language Learning_. There is a similar question there which has a short but good answer (see the link below). If you want more personalized advice you will need to add details about your context and the particular situations in which you lack the necessary words. https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-are-the-most-effective-ways-of-learning-vocabulary-of-any-language

Comment: Learning more words is the usual method.

Comment: This is frequently asked, and normally closed https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61187/is-there-a-better-method-to-improve-ones-vocabulary https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78116/strategies-to-improve-spoken-english-and-vocabulary https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/245577/good-strategies-to-improve-vocabulary-when-at-c2-level https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/199117/how-do-i-improve-my-vocabulary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strategies to improve spoken English and vocabulary](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78116/strategies-to-improve-spoken-english-and-vocabulary)

Comment: There's a joke that D&D is the best way to pass the vocabulary portion of the SAT and other language tests, because fantasy writing tends to overuse flowery "obscure" synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

Consume language to get better at it.

You learn language when you are exposed to it. Read books and articles, watch movies and TV shows, listen to songs and podcasts, play video games.

When you come across a word you don't know or can't guess the meaning of from the context, look it up in a dictionary. When you have come across it a couple of times, you will eventually "know" it.

Try to broaden the media you consume. Read articles about the environment, watch films about political drama and play video games set in space. The variety of words you learn is directly proportional to the variety of language you are exposed to.

Comment: thanks, but I feel I cant remember them, do u have good idea to help me to remember them?

Comment: You remember them through repeated exposure. If over the course of three months you come across the word "loquacious" five times, you will eventually learn it.